# Why doesn't i get the session when i fetch it in react?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core, session, fetch

When i paste the endpoint int the browser url and save and fetch the session it works.

But when i try it with react fetch like this:

```
fetch(`https://localhost:44369/api/users/save-to-session?userId=${userId}`, {
  method: "GET",
  mode: "cors",
  credentials: "include",
}).then(() => {
  fetch(`https://localhost:44369/api/users/fetch-from-session`, {
    method: "GET",
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "include",
  })
    .then(function (body) {
      return body.text();
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
});
```

I get null back.

This is the asp.net core web api endpoint

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("save-to-session")]
    public IActionResult SaveToSession(string userId)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("user", userId);
        return Content(userId);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("fetch-from-session")]
    public IActionResult FetchFromSession()
    {
        string name = HttpContext.Session.GetString("user");
        return Ok(name);
    }
```

It could be because of CORS?
This is in my startup file:

```
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddMvc();

services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });



   app.UseCors(options => options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowCredentials());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `Security` as true when send request with cookie from a `http` client to a `https` server

```
services.AddSession(options => {
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i was stuck with this error for soooo long. Now i get the session.